# print all root to leaf paths in a binary tree

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

i am trying to print all root to leaf paths in a binary tree using java.

```
public void printAllRootToLeafPaths(Node node,ArrayList path) 
{
    if(node==null)
    {
        return;
    }
    path.add(node.data);

    if(node.left==null && node.right==null)
    {
        System.out.println(path);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        printAllRootToLeafPaths(node.left,path);
        printAllRootToLeafPaths(node.right,path);
    }      
}
```

In main method:

```
 bst.printAllRootToLeafPaths(root, new ArrayList());
```

But its giving wrong output.

given tree:

```
   5
  / \
 /   \
1     8
 \    /\
  \  /  \
  3  6   9
```

Expected output:

[5, 1, 3]

[5, 8, 6]

[5, 8, 9]

But the output produced:

[5, 1, 3]

[5, 1, 3, 8, 6]

[5, 1, 3, 8, 6, 9]

Can some one figure it out...

Comment: We need more information to help you out. "_But its giving wrong output._" --> What's your input? What output do you expect (and why) and what's the actual output?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. But the other guys understood my problem and gave the required answer...

Comment: @jlordo: Input is obviously a tree given a root node. And expected output is: All paths from root to leaf.(Clearly mentioned in the question). And wrong output means : expected output is not coming...

Comment: Here's the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) on how to write a good question. One bullet point: _If your program produces different results to what you expected, have you stated what you expected, why you expected it, and the actual results?_

Comment: @loknath the fact that people guess right does not mean that your question was as clear as it could / should have been. Please do check out the checklist jlordo posted.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. i will surely follow...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Call the recursive methods with:

```
printAllRootToLeafPaths(node.left, new ArrayList(path));
printAllRootToLeafPaths(node.right, new ArrayList(path));
```

What happens there when you pass the `path` (instead of `new ArrayList(path)` is that you use a single object in all methods call, which means that, when you return to the original caller, the object is not in the same state as it was.

You just need to create a new object and initialize it to the original values. This way the original object does not get modified.

Comment: This really works, but I don't know what" new ArrayList(path)" is doing. Is it completely create a new path list, or it writes over the previous paths. When we say new, does not mean that we reset the path? I am just new to programming, your help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If it was parameterless (ie. just `new ArrayList()`), then yeah, it would be a new, empty, list. With the parameter `path`, however, it creates a new list and then copies the values from the `path` list. This way the content of the original list, that is `path`, does not get overwritten. You merely use the values of the original list, not the list itself. :)

Comment: If I am not wrong, this is because ArrayList is mutable.

Answer (score 10):

```
public void PrintAllPossiblePath(Node node,List<Node> nodelist)
{
    if(node != null)
    {
            nodelist.add(node);
            if(node.left != null)
            {
                PrintAllPossiblePath(node.left,nodelist);
            }
            if(node.right != null)
            {
                PrintAllPossiblePath(node.right,nodelist);
            }
            else if(node.left == null && node.right == null)
            {

            for(int i=0;i<nodelist.size();i++)
            {
                System.out.print(nodelist.get(i)._Value);
            }
            System.out.println();
            }
            nodelist.remove(node);
    }
}
```

`nodelist.remove(node)` is the key, it removes the element once it prints the respective path

Comment: Running your solution works.  nodelist, like node, is a local variable.  Say a node has 2 children and it processed the left subtree.  When going back to the node and visiting the right child, why does nodelist have nodes from the left subtree?  Since nodelist is local shouldnt it remember the list from that stackframe, where it has no knowledge of the left subtree?  Same reason that node would not be a value from the left subtree, because it was popped off.

Comment: @Jeevan when I write List<Node> L = new List<Node>() , it gives an error, and says remove the type argument. Do you know why? ( java.awt.List is imported)

Answer (score 9):

You're passing your list along recursively, but that is a mutable object, so all the calls will modify it (by calling `List.add`) and mangle your results. Try cloning / copying the `path` argument to all the recursive calls to provide each branch (harhar) with its own context.

Answer (score 4):

you can do this way also.
here is my Java code.

```
public void printPaths(Node r,ArrayList arr)
{
    if(r==null)
    {
        return;
    }
    arr.add(r.data);
    if(r.left==null && r.right==null)
    {
        printlnArray(arr);
    }
    else
    {
        printPaths(r.left,arr);
        printPaths(r.right,arr);
    }

     arr.remove(arr.size()-1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the correct Implementation

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<List<T>> printAllPaths(BinaryTreeNode<T> node) {
    List <List<T>> paths = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
    doPrintAllPaths(node, paths, new ArrayList<T>());
    return paths;
}

private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void doPrintAllPaths(BinaryTreeNode<T> node, List<List<T>> allPaths, List<T> path) {
    if (node == null) {
        return ;
    }
    path.add(node.getData());
    if (node.isLeafNode()) {
        allPaths.add(new ArrayList<T>(path));   

    } else {
        doPrintAllPaths(node.getLeft(), allPaths, path);
        doPrintAllPaths(node.getRight(), allPaths, path);
    }
    path.remove(node.getData());
}
```

Here is the test case

```
@Test
public void printAllPaths() {
    BinaryTreeNode<Integer> bt = BinaryTreeUtil.<Integer>fromInAndPostOrder(new Integer[]{4,2,5,6,1,7,3}, new Integer[]{4,6,5,2,7,3,1});
    List <List<Integer>> paths = BinaryTreeUtil.printAllPaths(bt);

    assertThat(paths.get(0).toArray(new Integer[0]), equalTo(new Integer[]{1, 2, 4}));
    assertThat(paths.get(1).toArray(new Integer[0]), equalTo(new Integer[]{1, 2, 5, 6}));
    assertThat(paths.get(2).toArray(new Integer[0]), equalTo(new Integer[]{1, 3, 7}));

    for (List<Integer> list : paths) {          
        for (Integer integer : list) {
            System.out.print(String.format(" %d", integer));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

### Here is the output

> ```
> 1 2 4
>
> 1 2 5 6
>
> 1 3 7
> ```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is my solution**: Once we traverse the left or right path just remove the last element.

**Code:**

```
public static void printPath(TreeNode root, ArrayList list) {

    if(root==null)
        return;

    list.add(root.data);

    if(root.left==null && root.right==null) {
        System.out.println(list);
        return;
    }
    else {
        printPath(root.left,list);
        list.remove(list.size()-1);

        printPath(root.right,list);
        list.remove(list.size()-1);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is written with JS but You can gain the logic.

```
function dive(t, res, arr) {
        if(t.value != null && t.value != undefined) {
            res = res ? `${res}->${t.value}`: `${t.value}`;
        }
        if(t.left) {
            dive(t.left, res, arr );
        } 
        if(t.right) {
            dive(t.right, res, arr );
        } 
        if(!t.left && !t.right) {
            console.log(res)
            arr.push(res);
            return;
        }
}

function getPaths(t) {
    let arr = [];
    if(!t.left && !t.right) {
        t.value != null && t.value != undefined && arr.push(`${t.value}`);
        console.log(arr)
        return arr;
    }
    dive(t, null, arr);
    console.log(arr)
}


//INPUT
const x = {
    value: 5,
    left: {
        value: 4,
        left: {
            value: 3,
            left: {
                value: 2,
                left: {
                    value: 1,
                    left: {
                        value: 0
                    },
                    right: {
                        value: 1.5
                    }
                },
                right: {
                    value: 2.5
                }
            },
            right: {
                value: 3.5
            }
        },
        right: {
            value: 4.5,
            right: {
                value: 4.8
            }
        }
    },
    right: {
        value: 8,
        left: {
            value: 7
        }
    }
}

getPaths(x);

//OUTPUT

[ '5->4->3->2->1->0',
  '5->4->3->2->1->1.5',
  '5->4->3->2->2.5',
  '5->4->3->3.5',
  '5->4->4.5->4.8',
  '5->8->7' ]
```

Comment: It's better to write comments and explanations of what the code does instead of simply dumping it.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Given a binary tree, print out all of its root-to-leaf
   paths, one per line. Uses a recursive helper to do the work.*/
void printPaths(Node node) 
{
    int path[] = new int[1000];
    printPathsRecur(node, path, 0);
}

/* Recursive helper function -- given a node, and an array containing
   the path from the root node up to but not including this node,
   print out all the root-leaf paths. */
void printPathsRecur(Node node, int path[], int pathLen) 
{
    if (node == null)
        return;

    /* append this node to the path array */
    path[pathLen] = node.data;
    pathLen++;

    /* it's a leaf, so print the path that led to here */
    if (node.left == null && node.right == null)
        printArray(path, pathLen);
    else
        { 
        /* otherwise try both subtrees */
        printPathsRecur(node.left, path, pathLen);
        printPathsRecur(node.right, path, pathLen);
    }
}

/* Utility that prints out an array on a line */
void printArray(int ints[], int len) 
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) 
        System.out.print(ints[i] + " ");
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this problem with an `ArrayList` and my program printed similar paths.

So I modified my logic to work correctly by maintaining an internal `count`, here is how I did it.

```
private void printPaths(BinaryNode node, List<Integer> paths, int endIndex) {
        if (node == null)
            return;
        paths.add(endIndex, node.data);
        endIndex++;
        if (node.left == null && node.right == null) {
            //found the leaf node, print this path
            printPathList(paths, endIndex);
        } else {
            printPaths(node.left, paths, endIndex);
            printPaths(node.right, paths, endIndex);
        }
    }

public void printPaths() {
    List<Integer> paths = new ArrayList<>();
    printPaths(root, paths, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use recursion to achieve it. Right data structure makes it concise and efficient.

```
List<LinkedList<Tree>> printPath(Tree root){

    if(root==null)return null;

    List<LinkedList<Tree>> leftPath= printPath(root.left);
    List<LinkedList<Tree>> rightPath= printPath(root.right);

    for(LinkedList<Tree> t: leftPath){
         t.addFirst(root);
    }
    for(LinkedList<Tree> t: rightPath){
         t.addFirst(root);
    }


 leftPath.addAll(rightPath);

 return leftPath;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following,

```
public static void printTreePaths(Node<Integer> node) {
    int treeHeight = treeHeight(node);
    int[] path = new int[treeHeight];
    printTreePathsRec(node, path, 0);

}

private static void printTreePathsRec(Node<Integer> node, int[] path, int pathSize) {
    if (node == null) {
        return;
    }

    path[pathSize++] = node.data;

    if (node.left == null & node.right == null) {
        for (int j = 0; j < pathSize; j++ ) {
            System.out.print(path[j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

     printTreePathsRec(node.left, path, pathSize);
     printTreePathsRec(node.right, path, pathSize);
}
```

---

```
public static int treeHeight(Node<Integer> root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (root.left != null) {
        treeHeight(root.left);
    }

    if (root.right != null) {
        treeHeight(root.right);
    }

    return Math.max(treeHeight(root.left), treeHeight(root.right)) + 1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for storing all path values in List and then just print the list

Basically what code is recursively calling rootToLeafPaths method and passing the string on values separated by comma (","). The base condition for recursive function is when we reach leaf node (both children are null). At that time, we are just extracting int values from string and storing it in List

```
class Solution {
    public void printBTfromRootToLeaf (TreeNode root) {
        if(root == null) return 0;
        if (root.left == null & root.right == null) return 1;
        List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList();
        rootToLeafPaths(root, res, "");
        System.out.println(res);
    }
private void rootToLeafPaths(TreeNode root, List<List<Integer>> res, String curr) {
        if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
            String[] vals = curr.split(",");
            List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String val : vals) temp.add(Integer.parseInt(val));
            temp.add(root.val);
            res.add(new ArrayList<>(temp));
        }
        if (root.left != null) rootToLeafPaths(root.left, res, curr + root.val + ",");
        if (root.right != null) rootToLeafPaths(root.right, res, curr + root.val + ",");
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/26221993)