# Find the depth of each node in a binary tree in R?

Tags: r, binary-tree

This question has been asked a few times but they are all in different languages (for example, see [here for java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281399/finding-the-depth-of-a-binary-tree) and [here for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59666613/finding-depth-of-binary-tree-in-python), but Im am trying to achieve this in R.

I have a dataframe of trees. My trees are ordered by depth-first-left-side traversal, as in the code below:

```
df <- data.frame(
  var = c("x2", NA, NA, "x1", NA, "x2", "x2", NA, NA, NA, "x2", NA, "x10", NA, NA, NA, "x1", NA, NA, "x5", NA, NA),
  node = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
  terminal = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE),
  iteration = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  treeNum = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE 
)
```

The structure of the dataframe is as follows:

var = variable name (if terminal node or stump, then this is just NA)

node = node number

terminal = if the node is a terminal node or not.

iteration = Iteration number

treeNum = the tree number

As you can see, my dataframe contains 3 trees over 2 iterations.

For clarity, if we look at a single tree (eg, tree number 2 in iteration 1), it would look like the following image (where the nodes are numbered following the traversal method):

[image: binary tree]

And the depth for this tree (ordered in the depth-first-left-side method) would be: 0,1,1,2,3,3,2

Ultimately, I want to make a `depth` column to add to my dataframe, but Im struggling to make the code work. Any suggestions as to how I could do this?

Comment: Can you explain the logic of the data.frame?

Comment: Ive edit the question to hopefully clarify the logic of the dataframe

Comment: Still unclear to me... What is variable? What does each row represent?

Comment: In my case, I have machine learning model that uses binary trees to make predictions. The var column in my example above represents the splitting variable in the binary trees in the ML model. So in `df` above, each row would represent a single node in the tree and its attributes (such as which tree number it belongs to  etc)

Comment: It doesn't seem like you can uniquely reconstruct the tree from a depth first pre-order traversal. You need additional information. https://www.baeldung.com/cs/reconstruct-tree-depth-first-traversals

Comment: I am extracting the trees in that order directly from the ML model. They are ordered in a depth-first-left-side traversal style. So, when reading the df, we move in a downward direction, down the left branch. If we reach an NA, it's a terminal node and move to the next branch. So we always go down the left side, until we reach a terminal node and then continue the process on that brach.

Comment: @MrFlick Maybe Im misinterpreting that document you linked wrong. But it says "In order for us to be able to reconstruct a tree from its pre-order and post-order our tree must be a full binary tree. That means each node in the tree must have 0 or 2 nodes." All the trees in my example are full binary trees (ie each node has either 0 or 2 children nodes)

Comment: It says "pre-order **and** post-order". You only have one of the two. The binary part is not the problem.

Comment: @MrFlick So with my current ordering of trees in the dataframe df, it's impossible to determine the depth of each node? Any suggestions about what I can do?

Comment: You need more information in the data.frame. Not sure how you constructed it. But if each node pointed to it's parent, that would make things much easier.

Comment: The structure of the dataframe is extracted directly from a BART model build using dbarts package. Internally they are ordering the dataframe that way in their package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess if you explicitly do have which nodes are terminal and which are not, then it is possible to decode. So here's a function that can calculate depth with that extra information

```
node_depth <- function(tree) {
  stopifnot(is.data.frame(tree))
  stopifnot("terminal" %in% names(tree))
  depths <- rep(0, nrow(tree))
  recurse <- function(idx, current_depth) {
    if (idx > nrow(tree)) {
      return(idx)
    }
    depths[idx] <<- current_depth
    if (tree$terminal[idx]) {
      return(idx+1)
    }
    step <- recurse(idx+1, current_depth + 1)
    step <- recurse(step, current_depth + 1)
    step
  }
  recurse(1, 1)
  depths
}
```

It looks like the tree you drew is treeNum==2 at iteration==1. We can run the function on that tree with

```
node_depth(subset(df, iteration==1 & treeNum==2))
# [1] 1 2 2 3 4 4 3
```

(you can subtract 1 from the vector if you prefer to start at 0).

We can run this on all the trees with

```
lapply(split(df, ~treeNum + iteration), 
  function(x) cbind(x, depth=node_depth(x)))
```

which returns

```
$`1.1`
   var node terminal iteration treeNum depth
1   x2    1    FALSE         1       1     1
2 <NA>    2     TRUE         1       1     2
3 <NA>    3     TRUE         1       1     2

$`2.1`
    var node terminal iteration treeNum depth
4    x1    1    FALSE         1       2     1
5  <NA>    2     TRUE         1       2     2
6    x2    3    FALSE         1       2     2
7    x2    4    FALSE         1       2     3
8  <NA>    5     TRUE         1       2     4
9  <NA>    6     TRUE         1       2     4
10 <NA>    7     TRUE         1       2     3

$`3.1`
    var node terminal iteration treeNum depth
11   x2    1    FALSE         1       3     1
12 <NA>    2     TRUE         1       3     2
13  x10    3    FALSE         1       3     2
14 <NA>    4     TRUE         1       3     3
15 <NA>    5     TRUE         1       3     3

$`1.2`
    var node terminal iteration treeNum depth
16 <NA>    1     TRUE         2       1     1

$`2.2`
    var node terminal iteration treeNum depth
17   x1    1    FALSE         2       2     1
18 <NA>    2     TRUE         2       2     2
19 <NA>    3     TRUE         2       2     2

$`3.2`
    var node terminal iteration treeNum depth
20   x5    1    FALSE         2       3     1
21 <NA>    2     TRUE         2       3     2
22 <NA>    3     TRUE         2       3     2
```

So while it's not generally that a depth first pre-order traversal can allow you to reconstruct the tree, it can if you explicitly know which nodes are terminal and which are not.

Answer (score 2):

Using preorder traversal and the fact that each node is either terminal or has two children.

```
lapply(
  split(df$terminal, df[c("treeNum", "iteration")]),
  \(term) {
    i <- 0L
    depth <- vector("integer", length(term))
    helper <- \(d) {
      i        <<- i + 1L
      depth[i] <<- d
      if (!term[i]) {
        helper(d+1L)
        helper(d+1L)
      }
    }
    helper(0L)
    return(depth)
  }
)

$`1.1`
[1] 0 1 1

$`2.1`
[1] 0 1 1 2 3 3 2

$`3.1`
[1] 0 1 1 2 2

$`1.2`
[1] 0

$`2.2`
[1] 0 1 1

$`3.2`
[1] 0 1 1
```

You can add the results to the data.frame with

```
df$depth <- unlist(lapply(...))
```